# mysql: how to have different order by based on field result

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table of domain, subdomain, path, action, type, user that I to have results sorted based on the action field.

type represents the type of record (2 = domain, 3 = subdomain, 4 = path).

for the results with action = a then order by action asc, path desc, subdomain desc, user desc;

and

for the results with action = b then order by action asc, subdomain asc, path asc, user desc;

I need all of the above to be in one select statement that selects based on domain, subdomain, path.  The select would start like:

```
select action, user 
from table1 
where (domain = 'testdomain.com' and type = 2) 
or (domain = 'testdomain.com' and subdomain = 'sub1'and type = 3) 
or (domain = 'testdomain.com' and path = 'path1' and type = 4) 
and (user is null or user = 'smith') 
order by ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Update ... Drew reported this as a duplicate.  There wasn't much for me to go on in the referenced question but I took the leap and here's the query.  The query did not work (syntax error):

```
select action, type, user from filterList 
where (domain = 'testdomain.com' and type = 2) 
or (domain = 'testdomain.com' and subdomain = 'sub1' and type = 3) 
or (domain = 'testdomain.com' and path = 'path1' and type = 4) 
and (user is null or user = 'smith') 
order by `action` asc, 
CASE `action` 
WHEN 'a' THEN order by path desc, subdomain desc, user desc 
WHEN 'b' THEN order by subdomain asc, path asc, user desc;
```

Comment: Is this query going to return more than one row? For example, if it returns 5 rows, how do you know which `action` value to use?

Comment: Yes, there will be multiple rows returned.  There could be three action = a and two action = b in the results.

Comment: I reopened the question Xi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but it will look weird... and you were on the right track:

```
order by `action` asc, 
CASE `action` WHEN 'a' THEN path ELSE NULL END DESC,
CASE `action` WHEN 'a' THEN subdomain ELSE NULL END DESC,
CASE `action` WHEN 'a' THEN user ELSE NULL END DESC,
CASE `action` WHEN 'b' THEN subdomain ELSE NULL END ASC,
CASE `action` WHEN 'b' THEN path ELSE NULL END ASC,
CASE `action` WHEN 'b' THEN user ELSE NULL END DESC
```

*I am guessing the syntax error you got was because you can't put an ORDER BY clause in a CASE statement.*